# Swapping vs. assigning with std::map [] operator (const issue)

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std

I'm currently using the [] operator on a `std::map`:

```
map[key] = value;
```

Nothing too crazy. However, my value contains a const public member:

```
class Value
{
public:
    Value(int input) : member(input) { }
    const int member;
};
```

Without getting into the details of my application, the const member is something we want to keep. Given that, I was assuming that `map[key] = value` was doing something like first erasing the existing value, then inserting the new one:

```
map.erase(map.find(key));
map.insert(make_pair(key, value));
```

However, what actually seems to be happening is that the `operator []` returns a reference to the Value, and thus tries to use the = assignment or move operator or something. Clearly, this can't work because the member can't be reassigned. Now, I'm OK with just calling erase then insert myself, but I was wondering if there was a way to pull off `map[key] = value` that uses this "swap" technique.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. How is the map defined?

Comment: Why wouldn't map[] return a reference? It seems a lot more intuitive to me.

Comment: I'm not arguing that it shouldn't return a reference, I'm happy enough with that implementation, I'm just asking if there is a way to do what I am asking. Let me ask this in a simpler way: if I make a map of type std::map<key, const value>, then [] can never work (due to returning a reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to implement a map like that in C++. Think about it: In order to do this you would have to make map[] return a proxy object with an overloaded assignment operator that then calls erase and remove on the underlying map, while also being careful to make sure it still behaves as a reference to its value when used as an rvalue. Returning reference is the only sensible way to do things, and is more intuitive as well.

As far as how to do what you want, you should probably just write a function to do so, and call that function instead of trying to assign elements to the map directly.

Comment: Yeah after the fact I noticed an easier way to ask the question would be "how can I use operator[] with std::map<key, const value>", which I suppose the answer is "you can't". My confusion comes from the ObjC world where blah[key] = value is rewritten by the compiler to [blah insertObject:atKeyedIndex:] (which obviously does allow to do this swapping "magic").

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you define your map as something like:

```
std::map<Key, Value> mymap;
```

Please note that the internal node of the map stores copies of your originally passed Key and Value. If you want to use swap semantics you should use pointers to Value instead, something like:

```
std::map<Key, std::shared_ptr<Value> > mymap;
```

and then to change the value will be something like:

```
mymap[key].reset(new Value(...));
```